# Working with two separate repos and syncing changes between them

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I am a somewhat new/basic git user and I'm having a problem that I can not seem to find an answer for.  I am trying to figure out a way I can store two different branches from a github repo locally on my computer.  My understanding is that when I clone a repo to my laptop from Github, it also downloads all of the branch and commit history my local machine.  I want to continue to use github as a version control/backup for my project.  However, I am working with colleagues who understand git less than I do so I am trying to find a way to help keep everything simple for them at the same time.

Here is a description of the situation:

- We are developing an analysis in RStudio to examine information about quantitative writing in college students.
- I am writing the R analysis scripts and want to maintain a safe backup with github
- I am sharing the project files with my colleagues via Google drive since they do not know how to use git/ github
- I have reached a point where I am going to change the fundamental file  structure of the project.  However, I do not want to disrupt their ability to perform analyses while I am making these changes.
- My colleagues need to be able to save analysis outputs to the project folder where they are synced back to me via Google Drive and then pushed to GitHub.

I can think of two ways to handle this situation but both seem to have problems that I can't see around.

> ### Create a branch in github, make changes to the branch and then merge the branch with the master
>
> > This won't work because I am sharing the files via Google Drive and you can only have one branch of a repo on your local machine at a time.  Once clone the branch to my machine, that is what gets shared via Google Drive and any changes I make disrupts everyone else's workflow.
>
> ### Create a second copy of my repo, make changes there, and then push those changes to the original repo that gets shared to colleagues via Google Drive ##
>
> > I have no idea how to do this.  Everything I have read discusses how to push/pull between different github users.  How can I do this as a single user?

Did I forget anything important?
Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in the same directory by adding a second remote origin, if you've already added GitHub as 'origin', then run:

```
git remote add gdrive https://example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

then you can push up your changes you've made to the two repos

to push to GitHub:

```
git push origin
```

and then to push to GitHub

```
git push gdrive
```

See this [github doc page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/)

Comment: Thank you, I understand better now.  I think I will still need to use two local directories otherwise any changes will be immediately synced to colleagues.  The info about pushing to a second remote repo is exactly what I needed.  Cheers!